# How to insert data into a view of one database without the dependency of a table of another database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-insert, sql-view

I have a View called View1 in DB1 and I have a table called Table1 in another database DB2. When I tried to insert data into View1, 
It's showing error like "`Cannot insert the value NULL into column PrecisionQueueID, table DB1.Table1; Column doesn't allow nulls. INSERT fails`"

From this error I understood that Table1 having the `PrecisionQueueID` but View1 doesn't have PrecisionQueueID. So when I tried to insert data into View1 it's showing error.

*Table1 columns:*

```
DateTime
SkillTargetID
SkillGroupSkillTargetID
PrecisionQueueID
TimeZone
```

*View1 Columns:*

```
DateTime
SkillTargetID
SkillGroupSkillTargetID
TimeZone
```

My Question is How to remove this link between Table1 and View1? I want to insert data into View1 without the dependency of that Table1 in SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to insert data "into the view" and doesn't insert this data into some table at the same time. Views doesn't holds any data physically. They are just... views

Comment: View data is fetched from the tables used in view source code. To insert new row into View, means inserting data into tables behind the view object. These are the tables where data is fetched. So the constraints on the table affects the view as well

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thanks for your comment. Inserted data into table that solved the problem.

Comment: @Eralper Thanks for your comment. Inserted data into table that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the AndyKorneyev's comment (Unable to get the comment link to cite) and [Eralper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942229/how-to-insert-data-into-a-view-of-one-database-without-the-dependency-of-a-table?noredirect=1#comment53709670_32942229) I got the solution.

As we can't insert data manually into the View, I just inserted the data into the table which is referring by the View. So I got the records as I expected.